# Getting default values from Backbone.Model in a method?

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to get the default values to use under a method.  It seems like `Model.get()` cannot be used within the method itself.  I have tried the two `console.log`, which displays the variable is not defined.

```
define(['jquery', 'Underscore', 'Backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){
    var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
        //default values for the function
        defaults: {
            rows : 9,
            cols : 8,
            baseScore : 100, 
            numBlockTypes : 6, 
            baseLevelTimer : 60000,
            baseLevelScore : 1500,
            baseLevelExp : 1.05, 
        },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log(this.get(numBlockTypes));
            //console.log(numBlockTypes);
        }
    }),

    game = new Game;

    return game;
});
```

Comment: Try using numBlockTypes within quotes, like this:             console.log(this.get("numBlockTypes"));

Comment: yep, i was just going to post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both @Elvis D'Souza and I came up with the same answer at the same time.

**Need quotes**

```
console.log(this.get('numBlockTypes'));
```

Comment: @klass-ivan is correct, this question specifically asks for "default" values, not "current" values

Answer (score 5):

According to your question (get **default** values), the answer should be

```
this.defaults.numBlockTypes
```

Mentioned method

```
this.get("numBlockTypes")
```

returns **current** (set) values.